# Search issue on special Character

Tags: search, characters

I have imported posts from RSS Feed and then on word press default search if i search

```
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum – Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
```

It shows me 0 result.

```
But on changing special character – to - my keyboard minus sign
```

it will work fine and shows desired result

Please anyone help me out there for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

By copying and pasting each dash into a Unicode lookup (linked below), you can see the two characters are different.

Your first string contains an [En Dash](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%E2%80%93), which is a different character value than the second string, which is a [Hyphen Minus](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=-).

When performing a search, WordPress is searching for the Em Dash value in your database, which may not exist. I would double-check the RSS Feed you imported to see which character appears in the content.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tom
Yes that's what i also find out As, the Search query will work on post title and content so it is possible to change utf8mb4_unicode_ci to utf8_general_ci ,
As, i will updated it gives me following error Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\xA4\xAC' for column 'post_title' at row 593
Please have a look if the following changes will work.

Comment: Is there any way to allow all special character to search would work ?